# what is the type of this filter?

Tags: control-theory

I'm successfully using an ad-hoc nonlinear filter for a particular application. However, despite searching Wikipedia for filter types, it's not known to me what it is.

The purpose of the filter is to return close-to-idempotent values while quickly reacting to change. The values are a real-time continuous stream.

I'm sure that if there's such a filter type/class, the published solutions are better than what I came up with. What is that filter's type/description?

In case there's no precise description of the filter that'd let me search for others, what are proper designs for the same purpose?

Please note, the RC filter performs very poorly for the same purpose. The data is from head tracking, where most of the "noise" is actual minor head movement.

---

Hopefully this pseudocode-like explanation is enough:

Let $K$ be a scaling constant, assume a small fraction on $[0, 1]$
Let $Y$ be the previous value, initially zero
$f(x) = x^2$

Within a single iteration:

Let $x$ be the received value, assume it's on the $[-180, 180]$ interval
Let $t$ be a time delta from the last iteration in seconds. Assume a very small fraction of a second.

Let $x'$ be $x - Y$
Let $S$ be $signum(x')$

Now, $Y = Y + (t)(S)min(|x'|, f((K)|x'|))$

Treat $Y$ as the value after filtering.

Comment: So, am I get it right you need a way to ignore sporadic changes (as they're mostly to be measurement error artifacts) and same time need to react on trendy changes?

Comment: You mention that the values are real-time and continuous, but also mention FIR (which is normally applied to discrete time data).

Comment: Yury, it's meant to respond fast to significant changes while responding slow to smaller changes. Consider response based on $x^2$.

Comment: Kwin, I may be wrong on the FIR part. It's moving toward the commanded value, and given ideal numerical precision will eventually be equal to it. I'm removing the FIR part of the post.

Comment: Are you able to provide the dynamics? It is difficult to know what you are talking about just from your description.

Comment: @SZN is the addition to the toplevel post enough?